# Getting error Missing required package "azureml-dataset-runtime" in VSCode

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am trying to setup my virtual environment for Azure in VS Code. I have installed the required packages, e.g., `azureml-core` and `azureml-widgets` and `azureml-dataset-runtime`. Both `azureml-core` and `azureml-widget` work fine, however, I keep getting an error missing required package for `azureml-dataset-runtime` although I installed it.

I have Python 3.7 and Python 3.8 installed, both 64 bit and I tried both of them in my virtual environment, still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the logs of uninstalling and installing the azure-dataset-runtime package?  I ran into a similar issue and my problem was that the package was dependent on a sub package which was not playing well with an existing version already installed by the other package (azureml-core)

Comment: I also got ugly issues regarding the installation of `azureml-dataset-runtime` particularly with `Numpy` version and other dependencies which finally setting python version to `3.8` instead of `3.10` solved the problem.

Comment: have you tried to set specific version of the package, like `azureml-dataset-runtime = ">=1.54.0,<1.55.0"` or similar? this is for poetry but the idea should be the same. not much info given for this question though